# multiple rows validation in PrimeFaces

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with validation of input fields in a dataTable, which you can add / delete lines. I wanted to validate key params unique in whole table. I get it by incorrect way I think.
Here's a simplified version:

In xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.parameters}" var="parameter">  
<p:column>                  
  <p:inputText id="name"  value="#{parameter.name}">
    <f:validator  validatorId="duplicateInputValidator" />                   
  </p:inputText>             
</p:column>                
<p:column>
  <p:inputText id="value" value="#{parameter.value}"/>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And my validator:

```
@FacesValidator("duplicateInputValidator")
public class DuplicateInputValidator implements Validator {

  private final List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();  

  @Override
  public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {       
    if (values.contains(value.toString())) {
      throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "error validation", ""));
    }
    values.add(value.toString());
  }
}
```

In this simple case, it works, but if validation is also related to different columns (in this example: value) it will not work.
Is there any better way to do this? I was thinking about the possibility to retrieve all the data from datatable and validate them. 'findComponent' not working if I have repeteable rows.

Comment: check this: http://ovaraksin.blogspot.nl/2012/11/validate-unique-input-values-within.html might contain some valuable info

Comment: I am not sure I understand well. Is your problem to have *one instance* of a validator validate *multiple inputs* (and if so, omnifaces is your friend (see http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateMultiple , for instance) ? Or is it to have *multiple instances* of validators, *one validator for each input* ?